# Combining two tables in dataset results in only first table in datagridview

Tags: c#, sql

I am querying two SQL database tables in the same dataset. I've tried merging them, using union and different join methods. All seem to result without the data from the second table.

Here is my code:
`

```
public string c = My data source string.
public DataSet ds = new DataSet();

public void GetData()
{
    var select = "Select tblMainOrder.fldOrderNum AS [Order], fldBatchName As Batch, fldShipWeekDate AS [Ship Week], Trim(Concat(fldFinishDesc, ' ', fldSpecialFX1Desc, ' ', fldSpecialFX2Desc, ' ', fldSpecialFX3Desc, ' ', fldSpecialFX4Desc, ' ', fldSpecialFinishName, ' ', fldFinishNote1, ' ', fldFinishNote2, ' ', fldFinishNote3)) AS FinishDesc, fldVarnishTypeDesc AS Varnish, fldColorSampleNum AS [Sample #], fldNumberOfCabinets AS Items, fldDateWritten AS Written FROM tblMainOrder WHERE fldOrderStatus <> 99 AND fldFinishingOrderedDate IS NULL AND fldDateShipped IS NULL AND (fldFinishDesc = 'BM' OR fldFinishDesc = 'Spec Paint' OR fldFinishDesc = 'SPEC PAINT' OR fldFinishDesc = 'Spec Stain' OR fldFinishDesc = 'SPEC STAIN' OR fldFinishDesc = 'Special P' OR fldFinishDesc = 'SPECIAL R' OR fldFinishDesc = 'SW')";
    var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(select, c);
    var commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
    DataTable dtData = new DataTable();
    ds.Tables.Add(dtData);
    dataAdapter.Fill(dtData);

    var select2 = "Select SUM(CASE fldProductID WHEN 'b' THEN fldQuantity WHEN 'w' THEN fldQuantity WHEN 'T' THEN fldQuantity WHEN 'v' THEN fldQuantity END) AS Cabs From tblOrderItems"; //Group By tblOrderItems.fldOrderNum";
    var da = new SqlDataAdapter(select2, c);
    var cmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
    DataTable dtCnt = new DataTable();
    ds.Tables.Add(dtCnt);
    dataAdapter.Fill(dtCnt);

    var select3 = "SELECT dtData.Order, dtData.Batch, dtData.[Ship Week], dtData.FinishDesc, dtData.Varnish, dtData.[Sample #], dtData.Items, dtCnt.Cabs, dtData.Written FROM dtData LEFT OUTER JOIN dtCnt ON dtData.Order = dtCnt.fldOrderNum";
    var dadapt = new SqlDataAdapter(select3, c);
    var cmdBldr = new SqlCommandBuilder(dadapt);
    DataTable dtFnl = new DataTable();
    ds.Tables.Add(dtFnl);
    dataAdapter.Fill(dtFnl);

    DGV1.DataSource = dtFnl;
}
`
```

Pulling my hair out trying to make this work. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are using the wrong data adapter. It looks like you want to use `dadapt`, not `dataAdapter`

Comment: Your `DGV1.DataSource` only refers to the last `DataTable` you created. I think the best way is to join the tables. Maybe if you post your sql join query and table schemas we can help you

Comment: What results do you want to get from each table in each row?  This is the key.

Comment: Presenting your problem this way none of us will be eager to help you.  You have to specify what data you want to get from Table 1 and the data from Table 2, and what is the relationship between the two tables.

Comment: My apologies. I want to get all the data from Table 1 combined with the "Cabs" field in table 2. I have corrected the DataAdapters as noted by Crowcoder.  The last group of code is where I am trying to join the two tables. The field fldOrderNum is common between both tables and this is the field I want to join them on.

Comment: Based on that dtData is tblMainOrder? in select3

Comment: Yes, dtData is fldMainOrder

Answer (score 0):

select3 = "select tblMainOrder.fldOrderNum AS [Order], fldBatchName As Batch, fldShipWeekDate AS [Ship Week], Trim(Concat(fldFinishDesc, ' ', fldSpecialFX1Desc, ' ', fldSpecialFX2Desc, ' ', fldSpecialFX3Desc, ' ', fldSpecialFX4Desc, ' ', fldSpecialFinishName, ' ', fldFinishNote1, ' ', fldFinishNote2, ' ', fldFinishNote3)) AS FinishDesc, fldVarnishTypeDesc AS Varnish, fldColorSampleNum AS [Sample #], fldNumberOfCabinets AS Items, fldDateWritten AS Written,(Select isnull(SUM(CASE fldProductID WHEN 'b' THEN fldQuantity WHEN 'w' THEN fldQuantity WHEN 'T' THEN fldQuantity WHEN 'v' THEN fldQuantity END),0)  AS Cabs From tblOrderItems where tblOrderItems.fldOrderNum=  tblMainOrder.fldOrderNum) as Cabs
FROM tblMainOrder WHERE fldOrderStatus <> 99 AND fldFinishingOrderedDate IS NULL AND fldDateShipped IS NULL AND (fldFinishDesc = 'BM' OR fldFinishDesc = 'Spec Paint' OR fldFinishDesc = 'SPEC PAINT' OR fldFinishDesc = 'Spec Stain' OR fldFinishDesc = 'SPEC STAIN' OR fldFinishDesc = 'Special P' OR fldFinishDesc = 'SPECIAL R' OR fldFinishDesc = 'SW')";

Unfortunately, I am writing to you from a mobile phone, and this editor does not support profiling the answer as required.  So use this query.  I can write a better answer than this later.

Comment: Tried it and I'm getting an error on ")", but like you said, you are writing from a phone, so I look forward to your answer later. In the meantime I will try to discover where the ")" error is. AND A BIG THANK YOU!

Comment: Yes, it is a logical error, try now